# Can not change site language in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to set the german language for the Wordpress backend.
German is also installed and can be selected under:

Settings> General> Site Language

Unfortunately it jumps back to English when saving.

My attempts so far:

**The following did not work (for me):**

1. wp_config.php WPLANG set and also removed
2. Looking at the database by setting, it is set to de_DE
3. Loco Translate installed and viewed. There, too, like the Site Language, it is output as English. Loco removed again. No WPML/Loco installed.
4. Checked for language updates, there were none.
5. Installed formal German and tried to select.
6. Language files controlled by FTP. Only German available, no EN.
7. Check latest Wordpress 5.8.
8. No Errors in Log Files
9. Test .htaccess, wp-content, wp-content/languages and all other subfolders of wp-content set to 777. Only for a sec. Really.
10. Deactive all Plugins
11. Other settings such as the time (UTC + 2) could be changed and saved
12. Activate all WordPress debug mode for developers. Nothing
13. `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` doesnt help
14. Check WP site-health.
15. Browser-Language set to german
16. Try another Browser

**The following did work:**

17. Installed and activated a Wordpress original theme "Twenty One" as a test

Comment: It may be a plugin that's overriding your language configuration. Try disabling one plugin each time and trying again in changing language. [I found a similar problem with WPML](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/cant-change-the-site-language/)

Comment: Thanks DanteNex. I deactivated all plugins but unfortunately it still jumps back to English. The backend of Wordpress is also partly in English.

Comment: Tried setting folder permission to all wp-content folder (not just languages) ? Also, try setting 777 permission to htaccess too.

Comment: I set all sub-folders (not files) to 777 as a test and the htaccess, unfortunately, did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since only the theme change worked, it had to be due to the theme. So I scoured the files and found it here:

The code says, and this was confirmed to me by support when I asked, that if "Deactivate translations" is not active in the theme options, absolute is set to en_US.

```
function et_divi_maybe_change_frontend_locale( $locale ) {
    $option_name   = 'divi_disable_translations';
    $theme_options = get_option( 'et_divi' );

    $disable_translations = isset ( $theme_options[ $option_name ] ) ? $theme_options[ $option_name ] : false;

    if ( 'on' === $disable_translations ) {
        return 'en_US';
    }

    return $locale;
}
add_filter( 'locale', 'et_divi_maybe_change_frontend_locale' );
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Divi was blocking any language changes. It can easily be fixed in the Divi > Theme-Options > General > Scroll all the way down.